# how to move inside an array trasformed into an as.data.frame?

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

I have written the following code to declare an array as data frame:

```
b=as.data.frame(array(0,dim=c(NF,29,1,T+1),
dimnames=list(NULL,c(…..varnames))))
```

Now, I am not able to move inside the array.. for instance, if I need to show all the matrices in the following array position `[,,1,1]`, what I need to write?
I have tried code like:

```
b$[].1.1
b$,1.1
b[,,1,1]"
```

but, of course, it does not work.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Your code gives an error. Can you share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: b=as.data.frame(array(0,dim=c(3,4,1,5),
dimnames=list(NULL,c("v1","v2","v3","v4"))))

Comment: That one should work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from `?as.data.frame` :

> Arrays can be converted to data frames. One-dimensional arrays are
>   treated like vectors and two-dimensional arrays like matrices. Arrays
>   with more than two dimensions are converted to matrices by
>   ‘flattening’ all dimensions after the first and creating suitable
>   column labels.

```
array1 <- array(1:8,dim = c(2,2,2),dimnames = split(paste0(rep(letters[1:2],each=3),1:3),1:3))
# , , 3 = a3
# 
#     2
# 1    a2 b2
#   a1  1  3
#   b1  2  4
# 
# , , 3 = b3
# 
#     2
# 1    a2 b2
#   a1  5  7
#   b1  6  8
# 

df1    <- as.data.frame(array1)
#    a2.a3 b2.a3 a2.b3 b2.b3
# a1     1     3     5     7
# b1     2     4     6     8

df1$b2.a3
# [1] 3 4
```

Comment: tabella_micro=array(0,dim=c(5,4,1,6))

Comment: please edit your question with a reproducible input and an expected output, with what I have I don't understand what you want

Comment: How can I declare the variables names regarding the columns (which dimension is 4) ?

Comment: I write: tabella_micro=array(0,dim=c(5,4,1,6))

Comment: res=as.data.frame(tabella_micro)

Comment: but, how can I declare the names of var1,var2,var3 and var4?

Comment: the clarifications should go to the answer, not comments, and I'm sorry I still have no idea what you want

Comment: Ok.. I posted an answer.. I am sorry but I am a practioner in R :)

Answer (score 0):

I need to create the a data frame, starting from an array which dimension is (2,3,1,3):

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Hence, the output that I need is:

```
debt loan stock debt loan stock debt loan stock
  0    0    0    0    0     0     0    0    0
  0    0    0    0    0     0     0    0    0
```

Is next code correct?

```
b=array(0, dim=c(3,3,1,4), dimnames=list(NULL,c("debt","loan","stock")))
output=as.data.frame(b)
```